# UITableViewCell allways show some subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some `UITableViewCell` with some subview. I need this subview to be shown on the top of the cell is selected and not. The problem is that this cell has `selectedBackgroundView` which hides my needed subview on select.

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
bgView.backgroundColor = someColor;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```

I tried also `cell.selectedBackgroundView addSubview:` but it didn't help.

*So the question is*: How to add some subview to the cell to make it be on the top if cell is selected?

Comment: where did you define your subview edit your code please. Define your subview after bgView and then try the same method.

Answer (score 0):

set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Comment: Read the question please, i have selectedBackgroundView so my cell must be selectable

Comment: I understood that you have a subview that is hidden by the selection of the cell and you still want to have it above even if you select the cell. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but selectedBackgroundView must be visible, and cell must be selectable

Comment: I noticed that textLabel ,image properties are not covered by the selection, so you could try to use one of those if your cell isn't customized.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a custom Cell, you can implement

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:myCustomView];
}
```

if not, the logic is the same, just in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method ;)

Comment: i think you forgot [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];, but setting bringSubviewToFront still doesn't help. My subview hides behind selectedBackroundView

Answer (score 0):

You must add your subviews to the contentView of the tableViewCell and not the cell directly.
Even if it is a custom subclass of UITableViewCell that you have implemented, you must add other subViews to the contentView of the tableViewCell. The contentView and it's subviews will not be hidden when the cell is selected.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourView];
```

Comment: i added subview to contentView, but it is still hidden after tableview becomes selecte